# Drop rows in Pandas where column value is not equal to specific suffix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose, I have a df having rows values

```
ID      Name   Age
ABC-123 XYZ    22
ABC-345 LMK    12
ABC-123-1 MNO   22
```

After applying a filter on column ID,
I need only the first two rows to be returned in this dataset case.
Like.

```
ID      Name   Age
ABC-123 XYZ    22
ABC-345 LMK    12
```

You see all the rows are excluded from the final result which doesn't match the pattern. All rows should be returned that match the pattern like ABC-123.
Note: Suffix number can be anything so I think it should be done with some regex to check for string pattern.

Comment: (1) Decide for one Python version and remove the wrong tag. (2) Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. (3) Explain the precise rule to determine which rows should be removed.

Comment: What is the filter ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['ABC-123','ABC-345','ABC-123-1'], age=[22,12,22]))

|    | id        |   age |
|---:|:----------|------:|
|  0 | ABC-123   |    22 |
|  1 | ABC-345   |    12 |
|  2 | ABC-123-1 |    22 |

df.query('id.str.len() <= 7')
        
|    | id      |   age |
|---:|:--------|------:|
|  0 | ABC-123 |    22 |
|  1 | ABC-345 |    12 |
```

Comment: This thing works. But I am wondering how it would behave if the data frame has a thousand number of rows.

Comment: it would work fine for even 100k rows